# Join statement for a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I have a table in C# and ASP.net that references a list of another table where several vehicle registrants are mapped to a single vehicle. I do not want to go through the whole collection of vehicle registrants by accessing their individual members (e.g. `vehicleRegistrantsAlias[0]`), because I do not know how many there will be.

Do I need to do this in two queries? I really would like to do it all in one. I have the parent class as vehicle and a child collection of vehicle registrants. Vehicle registrant is a base type and under a vehicle registrant is the owner and operator. I also want to pull information form other child tables. I am joining from vehicle to vehicleRegistrants which works fine; however, I also want to pull owner and operant.

```
Vehicle vehicleAlias = null;
List<VehicleRegistration> vehicleRegistrationsAlias = null; 
List<VehicleRegistrant> vehicleRegistrantsAlias = null; 

.JoinAlias(() => vehicleAlias.VehicleRegistrations, () => vehicleRegistrationsAlias)
.JoinAlias(() => vehicleAlias.VehicleRegistrants, () => vehicleRegistrantsAlias)

//from vehicle registrants
.JoinAlias(() => vehicleRegistrantsAlias[0]., () => vehicleSuspensionTypeAlias)
```

Comment: Can I make this any more clear? I would be happy to elaborate.

Comment: what are you looking for or how does the sql you want to have would look like?

Comment: The sql would get all the children's information form the collection of children. Sort of like a foreach loop inside a join statement. Can I join on the collection of children and not just the single child?

Comment: JoinAlias always joins on the whole collection and the alias indicates the for variable

Comment: so @JonathanO let me put it together and redirect me if i am wrong so tht i can help you, You have an entity `Vehicle` that had a collection of child entities `VehicleRegistrant` and you want to query for the vehicle that has a specific registerant with an operator name or the owner name so you want something like that `public Vehicle GetVehicle( VehicleRegistrant registrant)` that would return a vehicle object???? thanks

Comment: Yes exactly!! That is what I need. The joinAlias statement seems to not be able to work with a collection

Comment: wouldn't it easier done using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to NHibernate as well, it usually makes the queries easier to understand than the QueryOver API.

Based on the comments, I guess you want a function with the following signature:

```
public Vehicle GetVehicle(VehicleRegistrant registrant)
{
    var vehicle = session.Query<Vehicle>()
                         .FetchMany(x => x.VehicleRegistrants)
                         .ThenFetch(x => x.Owner)
                         .Where(x => x.VehicleRegistrants.Contains(registrant))
                         .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Or, if you have a relationship in the direction from `VehicleRegistrant` to its parent `Vehicle`, this would also work

```
public Vehicle GetVehicle(VehicleRegistrant registrant)
{
    var vehicle = session.Query<Vehicle>()
                         .FetchMany(x => x.VehicleRegistrants)
                         .ThenFetch(x => x.Owner)
                         .Where(x => x == registrant.Vehicle)
                         .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but I believe you get the idea. `FetchMany(x => x.VehicleRegistrants)` tells NHibernate to also fetch all the `VehicleRegistrants` for each `Vehicle` in the result set and the following `ThenFetch(x => x.Owner)` tells "and for each of those `VehicleRegistrants`, also fetch its `Owner`".

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Change variables to:

```
    VehicleRegistration vehicleRegistrationsAlias = null; 
    VehicleRegistrant vehicleRegistrantsAlias = null;
```

Change the JoinAlias lines to:

```
.JoinAlias(() => vehicleAlias.VehicleRegistrations, () => vehicleRegistrationsAlias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.JoinAlias(() => vehicleAlias.VehicleRegistrants, () => vehicleRegistrantsAlias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
```

And the query will eagerly fetch.

Also call before List:

```
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
```